# I am having a problem with python methods and classes (I think)

Tags: python, class, methods

I am a beginning programmer and am getting lost in a tutorial that I am following.  I want to better understand what the creator of the tutorial is doing but do not know what it is called that he is using for me to research.  For example, he has an object called sheet and then does "this" to sheet:

'''Sheet.range('A12').expand('down').value'''

what are .expand and .value called?  I want to research what these items are but do not know their name to start my search.

Answer (score 0):

**expand()** is a method. **value** is a property.